# Using private abstract method in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I do not understand the following restriction:

```
class Base
{    
    virtual doFoo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void doStuff() { doFoo(); } //compile error, doFoo is a private member of Base    
};
```

The solution is of course to re-declare the member in the derived class but it seems somewhat odd to me:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void doStuff() { doFoo(); }

private:
    virtual doFoo() = 0;
};
```

Why cannot I use the base class' abstract virtual private method in the derived class without re-declaring it? It seems to be overly rigid restriction because if I used it but not defined it then `Derived` is still abstract and to instantiate it some further derived class would have to provide `doFoo`.

Intuitively I would say that by not defining it (or re-declaring it) I imply that method is not used and is not part of the derived class but that is more for the reader of the code than for the compiler. Or maybe the compiler does need that information as well and that is the real reason for this?

Comment: Why not use `protected`? I am probably missing something

Comment: These are basics of encapsulation. Private is private, thats it. If you as a class designer want to expose something to the subclasses use protected and if you want expose your functionality to all clients (and subclasses in this case) use public.

Comment: IMHO, a private virtual method does not make much sense. Virtual means that is could be overriden by subclasses, and private means not accessible from base classes... Do you mean protected instead?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is actually useful to further restrict the access. If Derived implemented doFoo then further derived classes would not be able to call that implementation. With protected they would be able to call it.

Comment: Then `Derived` should be declared as `class Derived : private Base {...`. And not further derived class will have access to the `Derived` class implementation. But making the method private in the base class will certainly miss the point... Hmm this really looks like an XY problem. Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am using Template Method pattern so that is not an option. In my scenario I have an interface that derives from more basic interface (I have basically split an interface into two) and it adds only few subtle things to it and it happens to call some of the pure virtuals without actually defining any. The correct "solution" is to re-declare them and not to break the pattern. I am however asking why it has to be like that. The answers so far boils down to "because it is"...

Comment: @SergeBallesta "and private means not accessible from ***base classes***..."? clerical error? I think it should be ***derived classes*** other than  ***base classes***. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private base class functions can not be called directly within derived class methods. However this inaccessibility by the derived class does not have anything to do with the virtual call mechanism, which is to the derived class.

There are cases where this is desirable. Taken from the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#private-virtuals).

> You might ask, What good is a method that the derived class can’t call? Even though the derived class can’t call it in the base class, the base class can call it which effectively calls down to the (appropriate) derived class. And that’s what the Template Method pattern is all about.
>
> Think of “Back to the Future.” Assume the base class is written last year, and you are about to create a new derived class later today. The base class’ methods, which might have been compiled and stuck into a library months ago, will call the private (or protected) virtual, and that will effectively “call into the future” - the code which was compiled months ago will call code that doesn’t even exist yet - code you are about to write in the next few minutes. You can’t access private members of the base class - you can’t reach into the past, but the past can reach into the future and call your methods which you haven’t even written yet.

Comment: So essentially what that link says further down is "copy code". I can live with the redeclaration but I was really wondering whether there was some more important reason this does not work right out of the box (e.g. compiler inserting pure virtual re-declarations on its own if it needs them).

Comment: @ForemanBob "Even though the derived class can’t call ***it*** in the base class, the base class can call ***it*** which effectively calls down to the (appropriate) derived class. " What's ***it***? The `private\protected` abstract methods in the base class? Thank you for the attention for this matter.

Comment: @Resurrection "Even though the derived class can’t call ***it*** in the base class, the base class can call ***it*** which effectively calls down to the (appropriate) derived class. " What's ***it***? The private\protected abstract methods in the base class?How do you think about it?

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a new member function in the derived class does not give you access to the one with the same name in the base class. The one in the base class is still private, and you can't access it from outside the base class (absent friend declarations). This has nothing to do with the member function being pure virtual; it applies to all names. If you don't want it to be private, don't define it as private.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this method from a derived class, a good approach is to declare it `protected`.

Here, even if you don't declare the method as `private`, the default access of `class` is `private`. Which means that you are implicitly declaring this method as `private`.

(Had you been using `struct` instead, the default access would have been `public`.)